# Function for sum of fractions in R

Tags: r, function, fractions

I want to write a function to sum fractions. `x` is the numerator and `n` the maximum of `x`. I want to sum all fractions of `x/c` if `c = x+1` and stop if `c == y`.

For example, if `x = 1` and `y = 4`

```
1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 = 2.083333
```

Or, if `x = 2` and `y = 5`

```
2/1 + 2/2 + 2/3 + 2/4 + 2/5 = 4.566667
```

I tried a while loop but I think that's not even close:

```
score <- function(x, y){
  while (c < y){
    c <- x/1
    c <- x/c+1
  }
}
```

Comment: To get fancy and answer as a fraction: `score <- function(x, y) { MASS::fractions( sum(x / seq.int(y))) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Avoid loops in R when possible.

```
f <- function(x,y) x * sum(1/(1:y))
```

Comment: This is misleading. You can use loops, they should be avoided for simple procedures

Comment: A good rule of thumb for beginners is to not use loops in R. In particular loops should be avoided when iterating through large datasets. However, I agree that loops may sometimes be Ok.

Comment: Disagree again, depending on your task you may have to use a loop. Regardless, the statement in your answer is wrong

Comment: I'll change to "avoid loops in R when possible."

Comment: Thank you for the response and advice!

I actually would like to avoid loops, I simply didn't know it better :)